# How to delete duplicates of one column but choose which ones to remove based on the value of another column (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I see many questions about how to remove duplicates from a table in postgres but none that give much detail on how to employ some criteria to choose which ones among the duplicates to remove.

I have a database of companies that have two relevant attributes to this problem ('name' and 'employee_count'). I want to remove duplicates that have the same name field. But I want to keep the ones that have a larger employee_count. I should also note that the employee_count field may be null and in that case it is fine to treat it as if it were 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a delete with exists logic here:

```sql
DELETE
FROM companies c1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM companies c2
              WHERE c2.name = c1.name AND
                    (c2.employee_count > c1.employee_count OR
                     c2.employee_count = c1.employee_count AND c2.ctid < c1.ctid);
```

Read in plain English, the above query says to delete any company record for which we can find another record for the same company having a larger employee count than this one.  This spares the company record for each name with the largest employee count.  In the case where there be two duplicates having the same employee count, the above logic retains the record with the smallest `ctid`.

Comment: so to make sense of this, it is like looping through the table and then for each row it check if it is able to find another row with the same name but more employees (and in that case deletes it)

Comment: Yes, with `it` referring to the row currently being examined, not the one with a large employee count.

Comment: This worked well and ran surprisingly fast on my (11m+ table). The only complaint that I really have is that it doesn't remove duplicates in the case the employee_count is the same but for that I could just delete duplicates in the usual way after having ran the above query

Comment: Then we need some other primary key column to distinguish.

Comment: We can default to using the ctid in that case

Comment: ...and what is the logic for which `ctid` to retain in this case?

Comment: Well it would be arbitrary at that point. Could just keep the one that has the min(ctid) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this command.

```
DELETE FROM companies duplicates
USING companies
WHERE companies.name = duplicates.name
      AND companies.employee_count > duplicates.employee_count
```

I hope this help you. Let me know if it works. Thank you.